# Convert the cell to the formula with replace

Tags: excel, vba, replace

I have an Excel file with several sheets in it. In each "A1"-cell I saved my formulas as a text, in the format:

%=TR('Sheet 1'!C1;'Sheet 1'!$F$1:$F$5;"Frq=D SDate=#1 EDate=#2 Curn=EUR CH=Fd";$B$1;'Sheet 1'!$D$1;'Sheet 1'!$E$1)

I saved them in such format on purpose, since the formulas allow to connect via Add-In (xlam) to the database (Thomson Reuters Eikon) and are used to retrieve the data from this database. If I have them all in the file without %-character, they are exercised at once and file crashes. So I want to write VBA which deletes the character (`%`) in each sheet one by one, hence waits some 1 or 2 minutes until the formula in the previous sheet has retrieved the data. I tried several ways but none of them worked.

First, I tried to replace the character with this code:

```
Dim SearchValue As String
Dim NewValue As String

SearchValue = "%"
NewValue = ""

Selection.Replace What:=SearchValue, Replacement:=NewValue,      
LookAt:=xlPart, _
SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
ReplaceFormat:=False
```

and this code:

```
Range("B1").Replace "%", ""
```

But it only goes if I call the find-and-replace box and press the button manually.

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogFormulaReplace).Show "%", ""
```

How can exercise find-and-replace box with a macro?

Besides, I tried to generate formula with adding "=" to TR('Sheet 1'!C1;'Sheet 1'!$F$1:$F$5;"Frq=D SDate=#1 EDate=#2 Curn=EUR CH=Fd";$B$1;'Sheet 1'!$D$1;'Sheet 1'!$E$1) like this:

```
myformula = Cells(1, 1).Value
Range("B1").Select
ActiveCell.Formula = "=" & myformula
```

I failed either...

Is there some other possibility to replace the `%` character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the replacement into the [Range.Formula property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838835.aspx).

```
with selection.cells(1)
    .formula = replace(.value, chr(37), vbnullstring)
end with

With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    .Formula = Replace(.Value, Chr(37), vbNullString)
End With

'for non-US-EN systems you need to use comma list separators with .Formula
With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    .Formula = Replace(Replace(.Value, Chr(37), vbNullString), Chr(59), Chr(44))
End With

'for non-US-EN systems you can also use .FormulaLocal
With Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1)
    .FormulaLocal = Replace(.Value, Chr(37), vbNullString)
End With
```

VBA formulas setting is very US-EN centric; it expects that you are using a formula on a EN-US system. You can change the formula list separators from semi-colons to commas or use the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx) to accomadate the semi-colon list separators.

Comment: Thank you, I will try it out and report about the success later.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not worked. I used `Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Formula = Replace(Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(1, 1).Value, Chr(37), vbNullString)` and I got "Runtime error 1004".

Comment: There is a problem with the formula. I tested this on a simpler formula (e.g. `%=SUM(B2:B4)`) and it worked as expected. If the formula is valid then there should be no difference in the complexity of the formula. [edit] Unless that is expected to be an array formula.

Comment: You know you were using `Sheet 1` in the formula but just wrote `Sheet1` in the code line you provided? One has a space and the other doesn't.

Comment: I change the name of my excel sheet 1 to sheet1 in the comment on purpose ( I use another name at the original file), but  in the macro I use an original name. Simple example `%=SUM(B2:B4)` did not worked by me. The second code produced the error #NAME? (and only if my active cell was A1) and first code did not work at all.

Comment: If `=SUM(B2:B4)` in a cell produces `#NAME!` then you have a non-EN-US version of Excel. Use a simple formula that works on your own version of Excel.

Comment: Yes, you are right. With other formula the first code works, but  `TR('Sheet 1'!C1;'Sheet 1'!$F$1:$F$5;"Frq=D SDate=#1 EDate=#2 Curn=EUR CH=Fd";$B$1;'Sheet 1'!$D$1;'Sheet 1'!$E$1) ` still returns me "Runtime error 1004".

Comment: OK, I get it. I didn't notice the semi-colons used for list separators until just now. VBA is very EN-US centric and formulas need to be put in as EN-US formulas. See above for replacement of semi-colons with commas or alternately, using the [Range.FormulaLocal property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838851.aspx).

Comment: You was right, `.FormulaLocal = Replace(.Value, Chr(37), vbNullString)` works perfect. Thank you a lot!